# MIME Type Warning Causing Broken Image on Website

Tags: image, mime-types

Here is a sample page having an issue:

http://estorkdelivery.com/template/view/69

Our website serves up a template preview. Once you enter text information and tab out of a field, the website serves up an updated preview of the image with the text added to the field.

When the server returns this image:

> http://estorkdelivery.com/file/preview/verify_token:149505eb811f8856a12ec6e71e2932f082a97edf

It shows up broken with the following message in my console:

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: http://estorkdelivery.com/file/preview/verify_token:149505eb811f8856a12ec6e71e2932f082a97edf

Trying to cover all bases, I've verified the server has the following MIME types set:

> application/x-javascript  .js
>
> image/jpeg    jpeg jpg jpe
>
> image/png png

I'm not sure why this is happening. I was wondering if someone could help me troubleshoot. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Update 04/27/2012** - My question was marked down, but I have done research on this issue. If this question doesn't merit an answer, can someone at least point me in the direction I need to go in order to continue troubleshooting? I don't ask questions lightly and I have read plenty of similar issues on StackOverflow to find myself still with the same problem. It's discouraging to be marked down without a polite explanation. Thanks.

Comment: When I click that link I see a 404 page, not an image.

Comment: That is a sample link. I've updated my question description to display correct links and more information.

Comment: How is the request for that `verify_token` resource handled?  Is it routed to a script?  Please provide more detail.

Comment: It might help if you post your AJAX code so we can see how you're requesting your images.

Comment: @eggyal - I guess that's part of the problem. The way this system was setup, I don't really know what I'm looking it. So I can't answer either one of your questions. I believe I'm going to have to try and hire yet another developer to hopefully fix this issue. Thank you for attempting to help.

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot - Please see comment left for eggyal. Thank you for attempting to help.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not getting the MIME type error; which browser are you using?

Comment: @Yazmin - So, are you saying that you aren't a developer and don't really know what any of the code does? Are you simply unfamiliar with the technology of this system? Do you have access to the code or is it just a site that you are interfacing with and don't have any control over? We're willing to help, but all you've given us is "I can't get an image off my server and I think the server is setup correctly." We need to see code/configuration files to be able to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot - I'm not the original developer. This was a portion I contracted out. It seemed above my skill level (and clearly it is since I can't even answer what may seem to you guys as simple, straight-forward questions.) To answer your first two questions, it is a little of both. I do have access to the code. I should also mention this part of the site was functional until we moved the site to a new VPS server per request of the Magento developer.  So this may be a server issue, but I have compared both setups to the best of my ability and fail to see what may be the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I don't think it's a server setup problem; when your AJAX request comes back with a `verify_token`, I can use that to get an image from your server. Then, using JavaScript, I can get the new preview to display on the page.

This section looks odd:

```
new $._iframeUpload(form, {
  success: function(response)
  {
    $('.preview').attr('src', 'http://estorkdelivery.com/file/preview/verify_token:' 
        + response.verify_token);
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'http://estorkdelivery.com/file/preview/verify_token:' 
        + response.verify_token;
    image.onload = function()
    {
      $queue--;
      if ($queue <= 0)
        $('.updating').hide();
    };
  }
});
```

I don't really understand why an Image object is being created *after* editing the `img` tag. I would change your JavaScript to look like this (so that the `onload` callback works):

```
new $._iframeUpload(form, {
  success: function(response)
  {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function()
    {
      $('.preview').attr('src', image.src);
      $queue--;
      if ($queue <= 0)
        $('.updating').hide();
    };
    image.src = 'http://estorkdelivery.com/file/preview/verify_token:' 
        + response.verify_token;
  }
});
```

Try that and tell me if it helps.

#### Minor quirk

This isn't really in answer to your question, but it influences how this whole image loading process works. Your preview is 700 x 500, but the new previews that you're returning from your server are 2900 x 2100! That's making your AJAX load time much longer than your initial page load. You might consider sizing it down on the server side and then transfering it to the browser.